# Stepping over system/windows DLL

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am using the following command in WinDbg:

```
pc;z(eax !=12345543)
```

This will break at any call instruction, and then resume execution automatically (by stepping into the called function).
The thing is, I don't want to step into windows/system modules, because I am not interested in them.
So whenever there is a windows/system function called, just step over.

Does anyone know how to implement this in WinDbg?

Comment: "Debug just my code" for WinDbg...

Comment: I think that's a Visual Studio setting. I am using WinDbg standalone.

Comment: I would have thought that `pc` would step over the call and that `tc` would step into the call.

Answer (score 0):

set `.step_filter "filterlist"`

here is a scenerio where i stop on the first call to ntdll!ZwContinue from system breakpoint

```
0:000> .restart
CommandLine: calc

(6d4.ba4): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
0:000> .step_filter "ntdll!_*;ntdll!l*"
Filter out code symbols matching:
  ntdll!_*
  ntdll!l*
0:000> pc

ntdll!KiUserApcDispatcher+0xa:
7c90e45a e8ffebffff      call    ntdll!ZwContinue (7c90d05e)
```

that said your description of pc is not correct pc does not step into calls it steps over the call and stops on the next call if you need to step inside use tc  also be aware both of these commands starts executing the target

pc is p(Step over) followed by continue until next call
tc is t(Step in) followed by continue until next call

even as an example your expression inside z() is vague 
pc will stop on a call instruction like call 10345 , call ntdll!foo etc

are you looking for a call eax instruction ?

Comment: I have an application importing around 40 custom DLLs.
What I want to achieve is, I want to log all the function calls in a file, but without the windows calls. By doing this, I hope I will have a better visibility on the code path.

Comment: well if you want to watch the execution flow use wt (watch and trace) command  it has inclusion as well as exclusion lists  and you can set levels of entry  ( do not enter any third level call) iirc i wrote an answer how to use wt  http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/finding-execution-flow-calls-to-functions/6606#6606 take a look

Comment: Alright, I am using wt -ni -intdll , but i still can't see my custom functions.
My program contains 3 custom functions but all I see with wt are the ntdll calls.. what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: most of the time you cant escape ntdll ignoring ntdll often results in full execution of the binary for example if ntdll!ZwContinue is called  the return address of the call is not where the control returns after execution it returns to the context->eip  in such cases it is not feasible to trace if you think you need to know everything from start to end use apps specialized for such cases like api monitors